# Изменение масштаба изображения "на лету"

Tags: html, javascript, css

**Доброго времени суток!**

Вот возник такой вопрос: возможно ли как-то менять масштаб изображения еще до его прогрузки? Ведь, как правило, сначала оно загружается в кэш браузера, а уже только потом к нему применяется масштабирование. При чем масштабирование изображения происходит лишь визуально, но на самом же деле в кэше браузера и при первоначальной загрузке на web страницу оно будет реальных размеров! Можно ли это как-то предотвратить? Можно ли как-то "на лету" менять размеры изображения, подставляя их вместо реальных физических? Возможно, это может оказаться чушью, но в таком случае просьба разъяснить...

**Спасибо!**

---

Дело в том, что при загрузке на страницу, скажем изображения 1024x968 и более все начинает сильно тормозить( понятно, что при прокрутке, всяком динамическом эффекте все отрисовывается заново ), а мне хотелось бы превратить это изображение в меньшее по размерам и уже потом его загружать...такой вообще возможно?

Comment: Это могут делать только серверные языки программирования, например PHP.

Comment: @Нурбек, это уже соовсем другая тема!

Answer (score 3):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то вариант - грузить картинку в скрытый контейнер, напр., `<div>` размером 1x1px с `overflow:hidden`, сдвинутый за края экрана. И когда картинка догрузилась в него (и в кэш браузера), можно динамически вставлять `<img src="тот же url" .../>` в рабочее место на странице, с нужными вычисленными размерами.

То, про что Вы спрашиваете, кажется, наблюдается в GMail с примочкой для вставки картинок в тело письма. Свежезагруженная картинка сначала подгружается в маленький квадрат превью в масштабе 1:1, часто не влезая в квадрат. И лишь когда догружается полностью, размер меняется, чтобы вся картинка вписалась в квадратик 100x100.

Comment: Возможно, моя вина. Просто дело в том, что при загрузке на страницу, скажем изображения 1024x968 и более все начинает сильно тормозить( понятно, что при прокрутке, всяком динамическом эффекте все отрисовывается заново ), а мне хотелось бы превратить это изображение в меньшее по размерам и уже потом его загружать...такой вообще возможно?